# mysql float data returning different value

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a float value with many decimals.
My table

```
CREATE TABLE number_type_check (
    id INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    floatNumber FLOAT(18,5) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
```

When I run my query:

```
INSERT INTO number_type_check (floatNumber) VALUES (987654321.98765);
```

It returns `987654336.00000` not `987654321.98765`

Comment: Can you provided the `Select` or other query you are using to retrieve the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an usual rounding problem with FLOAT. You get a 4-byte-single precision FLOAT column, because your precision value is less than 24. You can't expect 14 digits precision from such a 4-byte-singe precision column, see [Single precision floating point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)

> MySQL also supports this optional precision specification, but the
>   precision value is used only to determine storage size. A precision
>   from 0 to 23 results in a 4-byte single-precision FLOAT column. A
>   precision from 24 to 53 results in an 8-byte double-precision DOUBLE
>   column.
>   [...]
>   MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you insert
>   999.00009 into a FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate result is 999.0001

Source: [Floating-Point Types (Approximate Value) - FLOAT, DOUBLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/floating-point-types.html)

Use either DECIMAL or DOUBLE if you need higher precision.

Have a look at [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2aa38/1).